# Writing a shell. "uninitialised byte(s)" when executing a command with a pipe

Tags: c, shell, exec, fork, pipe

I am trying to write my own shell in C. The code below works for commands without a pipe but otherwise does not.

Running valgrind with --trace-children=yes and --track-origins=yes give me a "Syscall param execve(argv) points to uninitialised byte(s)" (See the full error below).

In the relevant method (see makeargs below) valgrind is telling me "Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation" at this line "*argv = (char **)malloc((count+1) * sizeof(char*));"

Using my test input of "ls | sort" valgrind says that a "block of size 12 alloc'd". I do not see how this is possible because ls and sort each make a call to makeargs and both should be 8 bytes allocated beacause there should be 4 bytes for the char* then 4 for the (char*)NULL that execvp needs at the end of the argument array.

The program hangs after executing this command.

I am not sure why this is happening because it works if there is only one call to makeargs (no pipes). Any input would be appreciated.

```
void execCommand(char** commandParts, int pipeCount)
{
  const int PIPE_READ = 0;
  const int PIPE_WRITE = 1;
  int numCommands = pipeCount + 1;
  int newfds[2];
  int oldfds[2];

  int k = 0;
  for(k; k < numCommands; k++)
  {

    //more commands exist
    if(k < pipeCount)
    {
      if (pipe(newfds) == -1) 
      {
        perror("new pipe error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }

    if(fork() == 0) //child
    {
      //is prev command
      if(k > 0)
      {
        dup2(oldfds[PIPE_READ], STDIN_FILENO);
        close(oldfds[PIPE_READ]);
        close(oldfds[PIPE_WRITE]);
      }

      //more commands exist
      if(k < pipeCount)
      {
        close(newfds[PIPE_READ]);
        dup2(newfds[PIPE_WRITE], STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(newfds[PIPE_WRITE]);
      }
      char** args = NULL;
      int argcount = makeargs(commandParts[k], &args);

      if(execvp(args[0], args) == -1)
      {
        printf("%s: command not found \n", args[0]);
      }
    }
    else //parent
    {
      int status;
      waitpid(-1, &status, NULL);

      //is prev command
      if(k > 0)
      {
        close(oldfds[PIPE_READ]);
        close(oldfds[PIPE_WRITE]);
      }
      //more commands exist
      if(k < pipeCount)
      {
        oldfds[PIPE_READ] = newfds[PIPE_READ];
        oldfds[PIPE_WRITE] = newfds[PIPE_WRITE];
      }
    }
    //there are pipes
    if(pipeCount > 0 && k > 0)
    {
      close(newfds[PIPE_READ]);
      close(newfds[PIPE_WRITE]);
    } 
    //   if(argcount > 0)
    //    cleanArgs(argcount, args);   
  }
}
```

the make args method that gets called

```
int makeargs(char *s, char *** argv)
{
  stripLeadingAndTrailingSpaces(s);
  int k =0, count = 0;
  for(k; k < strlen(s); k++)
  {
    if(s[k] == ' ')
    count++;
  }
  count++;

  char* parts = strtok (s," ");
  strip(parts);

  *argv = (char **)malloc((count+1) * sizeof(char*));

  (*argv)[0] = (char *)malloc(strlen(parts)+1);
  strcpy((*argv)[0], parts);

  int i = 1;
  for(i; i < count; i++)
  {
    parts = strtok (NULL, " ");
    if(parts != NULL)
    {
      strip(parts);
      (*argv)[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(parts)+1);
      strcpy((*argv)[i], parts);
    }
  }
  (*argv)[count] = NULL;

  return count;
}
```

valgrind output

```
==3603== Syscall param execve(argv) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==3603==    at 0x40E2CDF: execve (execve.c:60)
==3603==    by 0x40E314E: execvp (execvp.c:30)
==3603==    by 0x8049069: main (cscd340_s12_hw2.c:250)
==3603==  Address 0x41c617c is 4 bytes inside a block of size 12 alloc'd
==3603==    at 0x4028876: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==3603==    by 0x8049416: makeargs (ush.c:100)
==3603==    by 0x8048E61: execCommand (cscd340_s12_hw2.c:191)
==3603==    by 0x8049069: main (cscd340_s12_hw2.c:250)
==3603==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==3603==    at 0x4028876: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==3603==    by 0x8049416: makeargs (ush.c:100)
==3603==    by 0x8048E61: execCommand (cscd340_s12_hw2.c:191)
==3603==    by 0x8049069: main (cscd340_s12_hw2.c:250)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I tracked the problem to my stripLeadingAndTrailingSpaces(s);

I had

```
void stripLeadingAndTrailingSpaces(char temp[]) 
{
   int len = strlen(temp), start = 0;  
   while(isspace(temp[len]))
   {
      len--;
   }
   while(isspace(temp[start]))
   {
      start++;
   }  
   memmove(temp, temp + start, len);
}
```

but needed

```
void stripLeadingAndTrailingSpaces(char temp[]) 
{
   int len = strlen(temp)+1, start = 0;  
   while(isspace(temp[len-2]))
   {
      temp[len-2] = '\0';
      len--;
   }
   while(isspace(temp[start]))
   {
      start++;
      len--;
   }  
   memmove(temp, temp + start, len);
}
```

There were a couple of problems with the old strip method:

1. I was checking '/0' to see if it was a space at the end.
2. I was not applying a new null terminator to the new end.
3. I was not reducing the length when cutting spaces off the front.

Answer (score 0):

You have some bad counting there: `count` is the number of spaces, not the number of words in the command-line. This affects the copying code:

```
for(i; i < count; i++)
{
  parts = strtok (NULL, " ");
  if(parts != NULL)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

If there are too little words in the input command-line, some trailing entries in `argv` will be uninitialized. You probably want to do something like this:

```
for(i; i <= count; i++)
{
  parts = strtok (NULL, " ");
  if(parts != NULL)
  {
    ... // consider using strdup
  }
  else
  {
    (*argv)[i] = NULL;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Your suggested structure is nicer then mine thought I do add one to count after counting the spaces so that was not the issue. I figured out the problem though. Thanks for looking.